# Using a widgetVar, how do I Disable or Enable PrimeFaces selectOneButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I’m using PrimeFaces 6.1 `widgetVar` to enable and disable multiple elements on a web page.  I’m using the following code:

JavScript/jQuery:

```
PF('widget_select_one_button_1').getJQ().parent().removeAttr('disabled');
PF('widget_select_one_button_1')..getJQ().parent().attr("disabled", true);
```

XHTML:

```
<h:form id="form-1">
  <p:selectOneButton id="button-1" value="#{search.drawings}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{search.drawings}" var="x" itemLabel="#{drawings}" itemValue="#{drawings}"/>
  </p:selectOneButton>
</h:form>
```

I have verified that I’m using the proper `widgetVar` because I was able to enable and disable a `selectOneRadio`.  When I decided to change the `selectOneRadio` to a `selectOneButton`, I’m unable to find any information on how to enable or disable the element.

I’ve used multiple variations of the JavaScript shown above. I tried calling `.enable()`/`.disable()` on the `widgetVar` variable, then using the jQuery object I’ve tried to add and remove the `disabled` attribute. I also tried the same (shown above) with the parent of the jQuery object.

Does anyone have a clue how to enable or disable the `selectOneButton`?

Comment: Disabling client-side is dangerous. Serverside it is still enabled. Clients can enable it again via javascript

Answer (score 2):

I used a css selector to search all the radio inputs through the descendants of these element and then applied the disabling function on each item :

```
PF('yourWidgetVarName').getJQ().find('input[type="radio"]').each(function (index, element) { $(this).attr("disabled", true); });
```

See : https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.

Comment: PF('yourWidgetVarName').enable() / PF('yourWidgetVarName').disable() should work perfectly on a selectOneButton ;)

Comment: @tandraschko Not on PrimeFaces 6.1, see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2881